# Listview not returning list of other Facebook friends with the same app

Tags: nullpointerexception

**Update**

**It now isn't getting an error, but the list of Facebook friends who also have the application isn't coming up in the main view after I log in, if someone could help with that, that'd be awesome. 
I have uploaded the project to [HERE](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/46531d308db7e48968b95e86088a24be20161211091152/998a02) for anyone to take a look at and let me know where I'm going wrong please
If you can let me know which file and what part is wrong, and how to fix it, that'd be amazing!**

---

I am trying to get a friends list showing who else has the app in someone's Facebook friends list when they log in, and I keep getting the error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference"

The error occurs because savedInstanceState is always null I believe, according to the debugger... any ideas? The full code is below:

```
package com.phinder.phinder;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public com.phinder.phinder.utils.Constants constants;
ImageView imageView_picture_profile;
TextView textview_nameprofile, textview_emailprofile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    constants = new com.phinder.phinder.utils.Constants();

    imageView_picture_profile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_picture_profile);
    textview_emailprofile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_emailprofile);
    textview_nameprofile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_nameprofile);

    textview_emailprofile.setText(constants.loginSharedPreferences.getString(constants.LoginEmail, ""));
    textview_nameprofile.setText(constants.loginSharedPreferences.getString(constants.LoginName, ""));


    try {

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load("http://" + constants.loginSharedPreferences.getString(constants.LoginImage, ""))
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .thumbnail(.1F)
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .into(imageView_picture_profile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
        Log.d("msg", "Photo " + e.getMessage());
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String jsondata = intent.getStringExtra("jsondata");
    JSONArray friendslist;
    ArrayList<String> friends = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        friendslist = new JSONArray(jsondata);
        for (int l = 0; l < friendslist.length(); l++) {
            friends.add(friendslist.getJSONObject(l).getString("name"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main, friends);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

I'm pretty new to Android coding, so sorry if this seems obvious!

I have added the manifest below also, in case that's needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.phinder.phinder">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>


    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here is an error log also (removed some personal information it put in there when retrieving from Facebook):

```
    12/10 23:40:03: Launching app
    $ adb shell am start -n "com.phinder.phinder/com.phinder.phinder.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.phinder.phinder.test | com.phinder.phinder
Waiting for application to come online: com.phinder.phinder.test | com.phinder.phinder
Waiting for application to come online: com.phinder.phinder.test | com.phinder.phinder
Connecting to com.phinder.phinder
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
E/Zygote: v2
I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1 ver=11
I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10412
I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [1], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0011
E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.phinder.phinder 
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
W/ActivityThread: Application com.phinder.phinder is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/art: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1439)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.phinder.phinder-1/lib/arm
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.phinder.phinder, real application class is null.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.phinder.phinder-1/lib/arm
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.phinder.phinder/files/AppEventsLogger.persistedevents
D/Package Name=: com.phinder.phinder
D/Key Hash=: zs7kzMXx78uDoJ9QjcsCuL2xPY0=
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.phinder.phinder/files/AppEventsLogger.persistedsessioninfo
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{802af0f I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x9e67f7c4
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [2560x1440]-format:1
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=2
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@266ed2f time:66569701
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.phinder.phinder/files/AppEventsLogger.persistedevents
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.phinder.phinder time:66595549
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{cb1dd37 I.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [2560x1440]-format:1
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=2
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@b071cae time:66595716
V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{1393c2f token=android.os.BinderProxy@266ed2f {com.phinder.phinder/com.phinder.phinder.LoginActivity}} show : true
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{9b1361b V.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
D/msg: Facebook
D/msg: fbid : 10154826532222425
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1952x720]-format:1
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=2
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@266ed2f time:66596446
D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.phinder.phinder time:66596581
D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@4d4175c
E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@4394d48
E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@4394d48
D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{f7ccc01 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [2560x1440]-format:1
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=2
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@5176ada time:66596826
V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{1393c2f token=android.os.BinderProxy@266ed2f {com.phinder.phinder/com.phinder.phinder.LoginActivity}} show : false
D/msg: Fb data1 : {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"id":"10154826532222425","name":"Dean Mokhtar","location":{"id":"109563165735553","name":"October 6, Al Jizah, Egypt"},"email":"mokdeabar@hotmail.com","picture":{"data":{"is_silhouette":false,"url":"https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/s200x200\/1471998_10152127224047425_6664922_n.jpg?oh=b5df53e5296ebea31a34126407b64933&oe=58EA2DCC"}}}, error: null}
D/msg: Fb data : {"id":"10154826532222425","name":"DM","location":{"id":"","name":""},"email":"@","picture":{"data":{"is_silhouette":false,"url":"https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/s200x200\/1471998_10152127224047425_6664922_n.jpg?oh=b5df53e5296ebea31a34126407b64933&oe=58EA2DCC"}}}
D/email: 
I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 55.0.2883.91 (code 288309100)
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 1 ms (timestamps 6941-6942)
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "55.0.2883.91", actual native library version number "55.0.2883.91"
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.phinder.phinder time:66596962
D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@59d2e50
E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@9e94849
E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@9e94849
D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.phinder.phinder, PID: 9793
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.phinder.phinder/com.phinder.phinder.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                      at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
                      at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
                      at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:92)
                      at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
                      at com.phinder.phinder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.phinder.phinder/files/AppEventsLogger.persistedevents
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9793 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace. Since you don't call `String.length()` anywhere in this method the error is happening somewhere else.

Comment: I have added a full log for you from the debug... honestly, I'm not sure how to do the "Stack Trace", so I don't know if this is enough.

Comment: and the String.length() is there for the list view to know how many items there are in the retrieved list

Comment: The stack trace refers to the lines starting with `at` following the Exception. It contains the exact sequence of functions that preceded the error.

Comment: Also `friendslist.length()` being the problem would show up as `ArrayList.length()`. `friendslist` is not a String object.

Comment: I have added an update to be able to download the project - the main issue is that the list isn't showing on devices now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
                  at com.phinder.phinder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
```

The error in question occurred in the constructor of `JsonArray`.
This indicates the problem is with the line `friendslist = new JSONArray(jsondata)`.

Since the error in question is a `NullPointerException` the cause is likely that `intent.getStringExtra("jsondata")` returned null, which it does in the absence of a value.

To fix the error either make sure anybody who launches the activity includes the additional data in the Intent, or check if the data is present and deal with the absence of data in your own way.

Comment: I realised that this bit of code was in the wrong .java file, so I have moved it and now I don't get the error... though I do not get anything appearing in the ListView (should show Facebook friends who also have the app) so now I have a whole new issue... 

I have one other person who has installed it, and they are definitely in my friends list, so they should show...

Comment: I have added an update to be able to download the project - the main issue is that the list isn't showing on devices now...

Comment: @DeanMokhtar You really shouldnt be changing questions. If you have a specific problem create a new question but SO isn't a free debugging service